# How read scanned driver license file in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a scanned driver license file in bmp format,is it possible to read license information in vb.net.

Please help me,how to read drver license OCR details?

Comment: I don't see how this is any different to any other OCR problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try [tessnet2](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/) a free OCR library for .NET